# serial port split data

Tags: c#, serial-port

In my code i send `Resume` and `Left` but for some reason the text is split like this:

```
[COM6] Pause

[COM6] Re
[COM6] sume
[COM6] 

[COM6] Le
[COM6] ft
```

here is my code

```
    var mySerialPort = new SerialPort
                {
                    BaudRate = int.Parse(nsComboBox1.Items[nsComboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString()),
                    PortName = nsComboBox2.Items[nsComboBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString(),
                    ReadTimeout = 500,
                    ReadBufferSize = 1024,
                    Parity = Parity.Space,
                    StopBits = StopBits.One
                };
                mySerialPort.Open();
                mySerialPort.DataReceived +=
                    (o, args) =>
                    {
                        string s = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
                        textBox1.Invoke(
                            new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.Text += string.Format("[{0}] {1}", mySerialPort.PortName,
                                s) + Environment.NewLine));
//removed the rest for being irrelevant
                    };
```

I think its because of my option but how can I avoid splitting the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using mySerialPort.ReadLine(); it will read until a new line value